# Object Creation in Android Componets

Tags: android

I am trying to make myself clearer in android component instance creation.
I believe any activity itself is an instance (correct me if i am wrong) but what would actually call " new " for object/instance creation? how does this whole stuff works in android framework... do we use super() in each component for that ? (to create that instance) which calls the base class's (Activity) constructor and it eventually calls "new" and creates the new instance for its derived class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to start an activity... you should call this method inside your activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);<--- here is the call for the activity(base) class..
```

without oncreate your activity will not have any instance..it will not start..

Answer (score 1):

You don't directly create an Activity instance, instead you send an "Intent" to tell the system to start one for you.
For more information on how to implement, start, and manage Activity, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)